# How can i solve this type of mysql error

Tags: php, mysql, oop

ERROR:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '@ami.com, '50cb0778758634b4a6f959ed4bf2debd')' at line 144

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                         <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" placeholder="Zip-Code">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input style="padding:7px 10px; margin-top:5px;width:336px;" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" >
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country">                    
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input style="padding:7px 10px; margin-top:5px;width:336px;"  type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </tbody>
    </table> 
    <div class="search"><div><button class="grey" name="register">Create Account</button></div></div>
    <p class="terms">By clicking 'Create Account' you agree to the <a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
public function customerRegistration($data)
{
    $name     = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['name']);
    $address  = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['address']);
    $city     = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['city']);
    $country  = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['country']);
    $zip      = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['zip']);
    $phone    = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['phone']);     
    $email    = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, $data['email']);
    $pass     = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->link, md5($data['pass']));

    if ($name == "" || $address == "" || $city == "" || $country == "" || $zip == "" || $phone == "" || $email == ""|| $pass == "") {
            $msg = "fileds must not be empty";
            return $msg;
    }

    // email query 
    $mailquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $checkmail = $this->db->select($mailquery);

    // password query 
    $passquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE pass='$pass' LIMIT 1";
    $checkpass = $this->db->select($passquery);
    // return $checkmail;

    if ($checkmail != false) {
        $msg = "Email already exit";
        return($msg);
    } elseif( $checkpass != false) {
        $msg = "Password already exit";
        return($msg);
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customer(name, address, city, country, zip, phone, email, pass) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$phone', $email, '$pass')";

        $inserted_row = $this->db->insert($query);
        if ($inserted_row) {
            $msg = "Customer data inserted successfully";
            return $msg;
        } else {
            $msg = "Customer data not inserted";
            return $msg;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: enclose `$email` with quotes too.. remember your code is prone to **SQL Injection**

Comment: Missing quotes in email at `'$phone', $email,`. Read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: missing single quotes $email

Comment: The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions. prepared statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is Here:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customer(name, address, city, country, zip, phone, email, pass) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$phone', $email, '$pass')";
```

You have missed single quote mark in $email. It will be like this ('$email').

So Your SQL Command would be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customer(name, address, city, country, zip, phone, email, pass) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$phone', '$email', '$pass')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You've missed `'` for `$email`;)

Try to change

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customer(name, address, city, country, zip, phone, email, pass) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$phone', $email, '$pass')";
```

to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_customer(name, address, city, country, zip, phone, email, pass) VALUES('$name', '$address', '$city', '$country', '$zip', '$phone', '$email', '$pass')";
```